# Não foi possivel localizar -lGL

Tags: c, c++, opengl, codeblocks

Eu estou rodando o codigo padrão do CodeBlocks para OpenGL no Ubuntu:

```
/*
 * GLUT Shapes Demo
 *
 * Written by Nigel Stewart November 2003
 *
 * This program is test harness for the sphere, cone
 * and torus shapes in GLUT.
 *
 * Spinning wireframe and smooth shaded shapes are
 * displayed until the ESC or q key is pressed.  The
 * number of geometry stacks and slices can be adjusted
 * using the + and - keys.
 */

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>

static int slices = 16;
static int stacks = 16;

/* GLUT callback Handlers */

static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}

static void display(void)
{
    const double t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    const double a = t*90.0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3d(1,0,0);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27 :
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;

        case '+':
            slices++;
            stacks++;
            break;

        case '-':
            if (slices>3 && stacks>3)
            {
                slices--;
                stacks--;
            }
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void idle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

const GLfloat light_ambient[]  = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[]  = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[]    = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[]    = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

/* Program entry point */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Shapes");

    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,  light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE,  light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT,   mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE,   mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Porém quando eu compilo/executo, o seguinte erro é exibido para mim:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/teste obj/Debug/main.o   -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lXxf86vm
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: não foi possível localizar -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Alguem tem ideia do que isso significa? Já tentei varias resolver o problema de várias formas, inclusive com soluções aqui do StackOverflow mas nada resolveu meu problema...

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Qual a arquitetura do seu sistema? (`x86` ou `x64`) E se possível, como você configurou a *OpenGL*?

Comment: Ola!! Minha arquitetura é x64. Fiz a instalação dos pacotes freeglut e fiz o link para "/usr/lib". Na pasta já se encontra um arquivo libGL.so mas não consigo rodar nada...

Comment: Como não sei exatamente como tá seu ambiente, eu sugeriria que refizesse a instalação da *OpenGL*, pelo repositório padrão do Ubuntu mesmo. Essa [wiki](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_com_OpenGL/Instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o/Linux) pode ser útil pra você. Qualquer dúvida pode falar ;)

Comment: Consegui fazendo a remoção de tudo e procedendo com a reinstalação dos mesmos... Não sei se tem alguma diferença mas antes, quando tentei remover e reinstalar, não estava usando o "sudo apt-get autoremove" apos usar o purge e dessa vez usei e deu certo! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Pode ter sido algum link simbólico que quebrou e ficou reclamando de falta de dependência, quando deu o `purge` limpou tudo, que bom que deu certo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer com que o CodeBlocks identificasse as bibliotecas da seguinte forma:

- Dei: `sudo apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-dev` e `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- Fiz a reinstalação de tudo usando: `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev` e `sudo apt-get install libglew-dev freeglut3-dev libglm-dev`
- Rodei o projeto exemplo da biblioteca Glu que já vem no CodeBlocks e rodou tudo certo.

Obs: A instalação já fez os link's automaticamente para mim, não precisei fazer nenhuma ação desse tipo.